# Qual a visibilidade padrão de uma variável no TypeScript, qual a importância de var ao declarar variáveis?

Tags: typescript, variáveis, visibilidade

Ao declarar uma variável, quando omitimos o parâmetro de visibilidade (public, private e protected) a variável é criada por padrão em que visibilidade?

```
export class AddEditTaskPage {

  idade: number;
  valor: string;
....
```

Só mais uma dúvida, a palavra `var` é opcional? Possui algum motivo em especial para ser usada?

```
export class AddEditTaskPage {

  var idade: number;
  valor: string;
....
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[É público por padrão](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/classes.html?WT.mc_id=DOP-MVP-5002397).

Em TypeScript, em membros de classe, o `var` é desnecessário, é adotado a semântica do `var` mesmo sem seu uso explícito.